# How to fix XPTY0004 error 2 items in one element in XSLT from XML to XML

Tags: xml, xslt-3.0

I need to make 2 groups for 2 persons if there are 2 persons in the base code.

At `value-of` the code mess up. If there are only one person its fine but when there are 2 elements with the same name the error **XPTY0004** show.

```
<reqpers>
    <person man="a"/>
    <esttime>8 minutes</esttime>
    <person man="b"/>
    <esttime>5 minutes</esttime>
</reqpers>

   <xsl:template match="reqpers">
        <xsl:element name="reqPersons">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="person">
                <xsl:element name="person">
                    <xsl:element name="estimatedTime">
                    <xsl:attribute name="unitOfMeasure">
                    <xsl:text>min</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(../esttime, ' ')" />
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <person man="a">
        <estimatedTime unitOfMeasure="min">8</estimatedTime>
    </person>
    <person man="b">
        <estimatedTime unitOfMeasure="min">5</estimatedTime>
    </person>
```

### I figured out that I could use the `a` and `b` to tell which to use. but I can not figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant element is part of the `current-group()` sequence so you can select it from there with `current-group()[2]` if there are only the two different elements you have in your sample or with `current-group()[self::esttime]` to select by its name:

```
  <xsl:template match="reqpers">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="person" expand-text="yes">
              <person man="{@man}">
                  <estimatedTime unitOfMeasure="min">{substring-before(current-group()[self::esttime], ' ')}</estimatedTime>
              </person>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifpK

Comment: hi i got a new problem. i need to  get "Operator" over in the atribut of <personCategory personCategoryCode=""/> i used <xsl:element name="personCategory">
      <xsl:attribute name="personCategoryCode">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="../perscat/@category]"/>
      </xsl:attribute>

Comment: @AlexanderLykkePedersen, consider to ask a new, separate question with the necessary details.

Comment: to answer my question i used this code  <personCategory personCategoryCode="{distinct-values(../perscat/@category) }"/>